# Septic tank issue

Tags: plumbing, septic

I had my septic tank pumped out two weeks ago. When bath water drains the toilet is still gurgling and the dirt on top of septic system is wet. Does anyone know what the possible problem is?

Comment: could be blocked vents, could be a failing drain field (in some parts of the country it's called a leach field.  Question:  when you say the dirt on top of the septic system is wet, are you referring to the septic tanks or the drain field.?  also check for any leaking toilets, it doesn't take much to saturate a drain field.   That or the drain field itself is failing.  Was there a reason you had the tanks pumped?  Were you having problems before it was pumped?

Comment: If you got the pumpout without at least a basic inspection of the system health, that's odd, IME. But it does fit the pattern of failing drain/leach field, call for an overdue pumpout, tank fills up from two weeks of use after the pumpout and the drain/leach field is still failed.